Representation theory of $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C})$
The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C})$ is not semisimple, hence not every finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C})$-module is a direct sum of simple ones.
However, do we understand the representation theory of $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C})$? I cannot find a reference for that. Can we at least determine all finite-dimensional, simple $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C})$-modules?

Yes, the representation theory reduces basically immediately to $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$. $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a direct sum of Lie algebras
$$\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathbb{C}$$
because the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C}) \xrightarrow{\text{tr}} \mathbb{C} \to 0$ splits via the map $\mathbb{C} \ni z \mapsto \frac{1}{n} zI \in \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, which lands in the center. So we can argue as follows. If $V$ is a finite simple $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$-module, by Schur's lemma the central $\mathbb{C}$ acts by some scalar $\lambda$. Then it remains simple when restricted to $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, because the central $\mathbb{C}$ acts by scalars, so a subspace is $\mathfrak{gl}_n$-invariant iff it's $\mathfrak{sl}_n$-invariant.
So $V$ is just a finite simple $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$-module on which the central $\mathbb{C}$ acts by some scalar. Equivalently, it's a tensor product of a finite simple $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$-module with a simple $\mathbb{C}$-module (which are $1$-dimensional by Schur's lemma).
The general finite-dimensional representation is an iterated extension of these, and extensions can be nontrivial. For example we can tensor any representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with a representation of $\mathbb{C}$ in which it acts by a nontrivial Jordan block; these are indecomposable but not irreducible, and are iterated extensions of copies of the same $1$-dimensional irreducible of $\mathbb{C}$. I think every finite-dimensional representation is a finite direct sum of these; the argument should be by considering the Jordan normal form of the action of $\mathbb{C}$.
Edit: This is true and it's actually easier to start with the action of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$. That is, let $V$ be a finite $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$-module. It is completely reducible as a $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$-module, so we can write it invariantly as
$$V \cong \bigoplus_i V_i \otimes M_i$$
where $V_i$ are simple $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$-modules and $M_i = \text{Hom}(V_i, V)$ are the multiplicity spaces. These naturally acquire an action of the central $\mathbb{C}$ which has a Jordan decomposition, as above.
Note that most of these representations don't exponentiate to $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ ($GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is not simply connected) and neither does that direct sum we started with (the short exact sequence $1 \to SL_n(\mathbb{C}) \to GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \xrightarrow{\det} \mathbb{C}^{\times} \to 1$ splits but not centrally, so we only get a semidirect product). In a positive direction, the algebraic (equivalently, holomorphic) representations of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (meaning the ones given by polynomials) are well-understood and in particular are completely reducible, because $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is reductive. So, if your ultimate goal is to understand $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, the complications here are not particularly relevant.
